# Javascript && operator behavior in chrome's V8

Tags: javascript, v8, interpreter

As I'm writing a javascript interpreter I need to implement some basic functions. I was playing around a bit in my Chrome console I discovered this strange behavior in js. How can I interpret what is js doing in this particular case?

[image: and operator]

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript's `&&` operator returns the left part if it can be converted to `false`, otherwise returns the right part.

So in both cases you are getting the expression on the right (since neither `012` nor `true` can be converted to `false`). For the first case, `true`, and for the second case, `012`.

Since `012` is octal, you are getting `10` output, which is the base-10 representation of octal `12`

I can't find a better link for a source, so I'll quote this one (it's not V8 specific, but should do): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

> **Logical AND (&&)**
>
> *expr1 && expr2*
>
> **Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns `expr2`**. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both operands can be converted to true; otherwise, returns false.

(bold is mine)

Answer (score 3):

The way I interpret the `&&` and `||` operators is like this:

```
a && b = a ? b : a;

a || b = a ? a : b;
```